# pause hash evaluation until initial ajax done

Tags: javascript, dom, hash

When someone first goes to my page, I create it from JSON using a couple of AJAX requests. I'd like to tell the browser not to try to scroll to the location in the Hash tag until after this is done (because the linked location probably won't exist yet).

Is there a way to do this?

Clarification:

```
mypage.html#l1.1.1

l1.1.1 refers to an object with id l1.1.1, that's the 'hash'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can't tell to the browser to wait, but you can scroll again when the ajax section is loaded.

```
$("#blah").load("/foo/bar.php", null, function() {
    $.scrollTo($("#" + document.location.hash)
});
```

You'll find the ScrollTo plugin [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

Good luck!